# Attach Javadoc to Eclipse for Java ME

Tags: eclipse, java-me, java

I have just begun developing using J2ME using Eclipse Pulsar and I am trying to work out how you go about giving eclipse the associated javadoc for all of the CDLCs. I am using the Symbian S60 5th edition SDK if that makes any difference.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the Windows>Preferences>Java ME>Device Management dialog choose the device that you are using and push the edit button. This should open a new dialog. You can edit the javadoc locations on the libraries tab.