# documentation missing in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, java-me, javadoc, java-wireless-toolkit

I'm new to eclipse/java Mobile development and all the rest of the keywords.

I have just downloaded the eclipse pulsar package, and installed it, i also downloaded the 'java me sdk 3.0' and installed it and linked it in eclipse. now i can create a new midlet and i'm using the splash template as a start.

now i typed: g.drawString(...) and i have like a string argument which is supposed to be the string to display. and other three integers.
Now the problem is that there's no documentation at all. it's like you have to guess each argument is what.
I'm sure there's something called documentation right? but i don't what where is it's the sdk ? is it eclipse? where can i fix that?
even the 'string' type i couldn't find it's documentation.

EDIT:
now in my installed jres i have only jre6, though i also have installed jdk1.6.0 but it's not appearing i added it now...

But the main thing here, is that i had to download something called 'sun java wireless toolkit' which suggested to download the new feature 'sun_java_me_sdk-3_0-win.exe'. and i did, when i installed it i have a new section 'window->preferences->javame' which also contains missing configurations.
but there's a section in it called 'device management' (meaning the device that i need to work against, like standard hansets configurations) each with a set of jars. And very few jars have javadoc location set.
i know where the javadoc is now, but it's not covering all the jars i'm working with.

so to recap: i think i'm working against swt sdk and i need to link the libraries taht i'm working against to their corresponding javadoc. but not sure since it's not supposed that 'Graphics' class or 'string' class be used from this sdk and not the default java sdk 1.6.0?
i think i'll take this day to try to fix all this and really understand what libraries i'm working with and if i can download the rest of the javadocs and use them. 
if it didn't work i'll go with netbeans. they say it's much easier to deploy

I did install netbeans, and the documentation is working. i saw inside netbeans that they are integrating the 'Java_ME_platform_SDK_3.0' but i don't know from where they provide the javadoc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my question is close to this question, you can refer to
[Attach Javadoc to Eclipse for Java ME](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4097825/attach-javadoc-to-eclipse-for-java-me)

anyway 
Konstantin Komissarchik has also answered correctly to how you set the javadoc location.

Now the problem is with the 'Java_ME_platform_SDK_3.0', anyway through setting manually the configurations of javadoc location, igot it working after i restarted the eclipse with -clean argument.
[image: good luck]

Answer (score 1):

I have a simple walkaround that fix this problem. Just go to the library setting, you will see the javadoc of cldc11api.jar is missing, give it the same location as midp21api.jar, restart eclipse. Hope this work for you.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have first-hand experience with Java ME development in Eclipse, but I will tell you how javadoc hookup works in Eclipse and you can investigate further.

1. Go to Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Installed JREs. You should find your Java ME install listed here.
2. Select it and hit Edit.
3. Expand various jar nodes under JRE system libraries. You will see source attachment and javadoc location.
4. If you don't see a location listed under javadoc, select that tree entry and hit Javadoc Location button to edit the location.

For me, using Java SE, I see location specified like this: http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/

It is possible that Eclipse simply doesn't know where to find Java ME javadoc. If you know the location, you can specify it in the above dialog. This could be a local or a remote URL.

If the location is specified and appears correct, the problem could be with network connectivity. If you are behind the proxy, make sure that it is correctly specified under Window -> Preferences -> General -> Network Connections.

Comment: thanks a lot , i've been reading a lot now, but there's too much configurations to be done, and i have to understand all that at first.

Comment: i've edited my question to answer you. And i also tried to set my network configurations, but i think the settings are correct. i'm gonna try to get the javadoc locally, or search for the documentation on the java website and try to set it thanks a lot